# symfony3 embedded controller with form

Tags: php, forms, twig, symfony

I have an embedded controller as described at Symfony's website. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

The only difference is that my controller has a form. All is rendered correctly but once the form is submitted, the request is always empty. Since the request is empty, the $form->isValid() and $form->isSubmitted() always return false.

Please find below my code:

Twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Controller:

```
public function myEmbeddedAction(Request $request)
    {
      $template ="myTwig.html.twig";
      $supportTicket = new SupportTicket();
      $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SupportTicketType', $supportTicket);
      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // success
      }
      return $this->render($template, array(
          'supportTicket' => $supportTicket,
          'form' => $form->createView()

      ));
}
```

Embedding the controller in my layout:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:myEmbedded')) }}
```

The request at the embedded action has always the same value:

> {"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}

However, if I access the embedded controller directly through the URL and fill the form, it works. How can I get the form to work inside of my embedded controller?

Comment: Just for grins try $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest().  When using embedded controllers you actually receive a sub request.  I would have thought that the sub request will still have the master request attributes but maybe not.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot. Could you add as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for grins try

```
$request = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();
```

When using embedded controllers you actually receive a sub request. I would have thought that the sub request will still have the master request attributes but I guess not.

Update: 2019-09-16

While the above code will still work when extending from AbstractController, it would be more in keeping with the spirit of Symfony to use injection:

```
public function myEmbeddedAction(RequestStack $requestStack)
{
    $request = $requestStack->getMasterRequest();
```

Comment: it seems to be `$requestStack->getMainRequest()` in Symfony 6