# Handling return form and redirect in service in Symfony5

Tags: php, symfony

Wanted to handle form as a service because I'm gonna need them in few controllers

```
App\Controller

$todo = new Todo();

$todo
    ->setOwner($this->getUser())
    ->setCreationDate(new \DateTime());
$form = $this->createForm(TodoType::class, $todo, [
    'userId' => $this->getUser(),
]);
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
{
    $entityManager->persist($todo);
    $entityManager->flush();
    
    return $this->redirectToRoute('todos');
} 


return $this->render('todo/todos.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView(),
]);
```

So I put it into service and it looks like this

```
class CreateTodo
{
    private $security;
    private $entityManager;
    private $formFactory;
    private $request;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Security $security, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, FormFactoryInterface $formFactory, RequestStack $request, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->router = $router;
    }
    
    public function createTodo() {
        $todo = new Todo();
        
        $todo
            ->setOwner($this->security->getUser())
            ->setCreationDate(new \DateTime());
        $form = $this->formFactory->create(TodoType::class, $todo, [
            'userId' => $this->security->getUser(),
        ]);
        $form->handleRequest($this->request->getCurrentRequest());
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $this->entityManager->persist($todo);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            
            return $this->router->generate('todos');
        } 
        return $form;
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't submit a form because `$form->createView()` doesn't exist, and if I replace `return $this->router->generate('todos')` with `return $form` it doesn't redirect me so it doesn't get updated before I refresh. Also is it a good idea to move forms to services if I'll use them in multiple controllers?

Comment: You are probably looking for [embedded controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers).  If that approach is not feasible then at the very least you will have to check the return value of your createToDo method.  I think you might be over thinking this a bit.

Comment: So to be clear, it's not worth to put this "form handling" method into a service? If so is there good way to make this form reusable?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and one possibility was using an embedded controller with this [symfony3 embedded controller with form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600672/symfony3-embedded-controller-with-form) to get the data. However, you can't redirect from there since it's in Twig...

What you could do is put the main logic of the form submission in the service make the form in controllers that show them. Then add the form HTML in it's own template and import it in the Twig views.

```
src\Controller\Todo.php

public function index(CreateTodo $createTodo, Request $request): Response
    $form = $this->createForm(TodoType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $createTodo->createTodo($form);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('todos');
    }

    return $this->render('todo/todos.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}



src\Service\CreateTodo.php

public function createTodo() {
    $todo = new Todo();
    
    $todo
        ->setOwner($this->security->getUser())
        ->setCreationDate(new \DateTime());
    
        $this->entityManager->persist($todo);
        $this->entityManager->flush();  
    } 
}
```